# Computer program to simplify formulas

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, computational-mathematics, symbolic-computation

What is the computer program that attempts to simplify sums of binomial coefficients, factorials, etc.?  Possibly Zeilberger wrote it, but I'm unsure.  If so, possibly it was talked about in his A=B book.  I vaguely remember these things, but my google searches have not produced anything, so I'm unsure.

Thanks!

Edit:  I aim to simplify expressions like

$\sum_{s=0}^k {n-l \choose s} {l \choose k,k-2,l-2k+s}\cdot k! \cdot 2^{s-k}$

I have also already checked through math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/programs.html.  Does the program EKHAD attempt to simplify such expressions?

Comment: The program most closely associated with [the book](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) *A=B* is a Maple-dependent package of programs EKHAD.  Is that what you were thinking of?  Other packages are [shown here](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/progs.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Amzoti and @hardmath!  I edited my question to respond to the above two replies.